# Validate with an specific field of a mongodb query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose and I have a car schema in Mongodb and each car has a schema for `typeOfCar`. I need to find out the `typeOfCar` value of and specific car and store it for use it later in a validation if.

All the queries and the connection with the DB work fine but I can't make my purpose.

Here is a chunk of my code:

```js
var typeOfCar;
Cars.findOne({carName : carName},{"typeOfCar":1, _id:0}, function(car){
  typeOfCar = car;
});
if(typeOfCar = "Sedan"){
  //something happen
}else{
  //something happen
}
```

Thanks and sorry my bad English :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check for `typeOfCar` should be in the callback of `Cars.findOne`. Like this:

```js
var typeOfCar;
Cars.findOne({carName : carName},{"typeOfCar":1, _id:0}, function(car){
  typeOfCar = car;
  if(typeOfCar = "Sedan"){
    //something happen
  }else{
    //something happen
  }
});
```

If you put the if/else block outside the callback, it will run before the statement `typeOfCar = car`. So keep it inside the callback, and it should work.

Comment: I understand, thanks, i'll rewrite my code. But its there a posibility of store the field value of the query result out of the Cars.findOne?

Comment: Technically, you can't. But you can use Promises or [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to achieve that syntax.